# Pyspark NLTK save output

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-2.0

I'm using spark 2.3.1 and I'm performing NLTK on thousands of input files.

From input files I'm extracting unigram,bigram and trigram words and save it in different dataframe.

Now I want to save dataframes into respected file in HDFS. (every time appending output into same file )
So at the end I have three CSV file named unigram.csv, bigram.csv, trigram.csv  containing result of thousands of input file.

If this scenario doesn't possible with HDFS, can you suggest it with using local disk as storage path.

Comment: How to save to local disk in case Dataframe fails to write to HDFS? is this the question?

Comment: @QuickSilver I want to ask to save files in HDFS with specific name and for every iteration of spark loop to append output in same file which is saved in HDFS.

If this scenario is not possible with HDFS, so Is it possible with local disk storage?

Comment: @QuickSilver Can you help me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991300/perform-nltk-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File append in normal programming language is not similar to what Dataframe write mode append is. Whenever we ask Dataframe to save to a location folder it will create a new file for every append . Only way you can achieve it by,

- Read the old file into `dfOld : Dataframe`
- Combine the old and new Dataframe `dfOld.union(dfNewToAppend)`
- combine to single output file `.coalesce(1)`
- Write to new temporary location `/tempWrite`
- Delete the old HDFS location
- Rename the `/tempWrite` folder your output folder name

````
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
    val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    /// Write you unigram Dataframe
    fs.rename(new Path(".../achyuttest.csv/part-00000..."), new Path("yourNewHDFSDir/unigram.csv")
    /// Write you bigram Dataframe
    fs.rename(new Path(".../achyuttest.csv/part-00000..."), new Path("yourNewHDFSDir/bigram.csv")
    /// Write you trigram Dataframe
    fs.rename(new Path(".../achyuttest.csv/part-00000"), new Path("yourNewHDFSDir/trigram.csv")
      ```
````

Comment: I'm saving unigram,bigram and trigram dataframes in three CSV files.
HDFS stores this files as
`/user/zeppelin/achyuttest.csv/part-00000-2af0dafe-3285-4f5b-9346-ec933b2b8350-c000.csv
/user/zeppelin/achyuttest.csv/part-00000-636e7a2b-2e2a-47c0-a54c-b867248f2ce2-c000.csv
/user/zeppelin/achyuttest.csv/part-00000-856905f7-77f2-4c3f-b826-2959d0d4cf1a-c000.csv`
So every time how to determine which file to read in spark Dataframe?
I want that single execution of spark program to process multiple input files.

Comment: 1. Write dataframe to DHFS , 2. Rename the file part-000 to hdfs using python HDFS API. you cannot specify file name in Spark . I have sample code in scala using scala APIs. if you want I can post it.

Comment: Yes please post.