# Perform NLTK in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new in pyspark and I have developed a program to perform NLTK on HDFS file, The following are the steps for that.I'm using spark 2.3.1

**1. Get file from HDFS**

**2. perform Lemmatization**

**3. Remove punctuation mark.**

**4. Convert RDD to DataFrame**

**5. Perform Tokenizer**

**6. Remove Stop words**

**7. Explode columns data to create a unique row for each record**

**8. I want to keep all files data into a single file so I am merging the output with old fil**

**9. Now write this entire merged output into HDFS**

**10. Then deleting old file and renaming spark created file to different name**

**11. I am doing this for all bigram and trigram files.**

Here is my pyspark code.

```
%pyspark

import os
import pyspark
import csv
import nltk
import json
import string
import re

from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer, StopWordsRemover
from pyspark.ml.feature import NGram
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf as sc
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,regexp_replace

import pandas
import hdfs



nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
nltk.download('wordnet')


from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
# conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PySpark App")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

hdfs_dst_dir = "/user/zeppelin/achyuttest.csv/"
counter=0

#Lemmatizen

def lemma(x):

    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
    return lemmatizer.lemmatize(x)



for i in range(1,50001):
    data = sc.textFile('hdfs:///user/spark/Patentdata/ElectronicsPatents/Link\ {}/abstract.txt'.format(i), use_unicode=False)

    print(type(data))

    if data.isEmpty():
        continue


    else:
        lem_words = data.map(lemma)


        list_punct=list(string.punctuation)


        len_list = lem_words.collect()


        test_str = len_list[0]
        test_df = test_str.split(' ')


        data_df = data.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(['lem_words'])






# Perform Tokenizer

        tokenizer =  Tokenizer(inputCol="lem_words", outputCol="tokenized_data")
        outputdata = tokenizer.transform(data_df)
        outputdata = outputdata.select('tokenized_data')




    # Remove stop words

        remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol='tokenized_data', outputCol='words_clean')
        outputdata = remover.transform(outputdata).select('words_clean')


#Explode one Row into multiple Row with value

        result_df = outputdata.withColumn("exploded", explode("words_clean")).select("exploded")

        result_df=result_df.select(regexp_replace('exploded',"[^a-zA-Z\\s]",""))



        print("Link  ========>",i)
#Merge with old output

        if counter>0:
            old_data = sc.textFile('hdfs:///user/zeppelin/achyuttest.csv/unigram.csv', use_unicode=False)
            old_data_df = old_data.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(['words_clean'])


            result_df = old_data_df.union(result_df)

        else:
            pass

#Write DataFrame to HDFS

        result_df.coalesce(1).write.mode('append').csv(hdfs_dst_dir)

        fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())

    # Rename file

    #list files in the directory


        list_status = fs.listStatus(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir))


    #filter name of the file starts with part-

        print("Get FileName")
        file_name = [file.getPath().getName() for file in list_status if file.getPath().getName().startswith('part-')][0]

        print(file_name)
    #rename the file


        new_filename = "unigram.csv"

    # Remove Old file

        fs.delete(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir+''+new_filename))
        fs.rename(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir+''+file_name),spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir+''+new_filename))



## Bigrams

        bigram = NGram(n=2, inputCol="words_clean", outputCol="bigrams")

        bigramDataFrame = bigram.transform(outputdata)




    #Explode one Row into multiple Row with value

        result_df = bigramDataFrame.withColumn("exploded", explode("bigrams")).select("exploded")
        result_df=result_df.select(regexp_replace('exploded',"[^a-zA-Z\\s]",""))


    #Merge with old output

        if counter>0:
            old_data = sc.textFile('hdfs:///user/zeppelin/achyuttest.csv/bigram.csv', use_unicode=False)
            old_data_df = old_data.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["exploded"])


            result_df = old_data_df.union(result_df)

        else:
            pass


    # Write Output in file

        result_df.coalesce(1).write.mode('append').csv('hdfs:///user/zeppelin/achyuttest.csv')

    # Rename file

    #list files in the directory

        list_status = fs.listStatus(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir))

    #filter name of the file starts with part-

        file_name = [file.getPath().getName() for file in list_status if file.getPath().getName().startswith('part-')][0]

    #rename the file

        new_filename = "bigram.csv"

        fs.delete(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir+''+new_filename))
        fs.rename(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir+''+file_name),spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir+''+new_filename))





## TriGram

        trigram = NGram(n=3, inputCol="words_clean", outputCol="trigrams")

        trigramDataFrame = trigram.transform(outputdata)


    #Explode one Row into multiple Row with value

        result_df = trigramDataFrame.withColumn("exploded", explode("trigrams")).select("exploded")
        result_df=result_df.select(regexp_replace('exploded',"[^a-zA-Z\\s]",""))

    #Merge with old output

        if counter>0:
            old_data = sc.textFile('hdfs:///user/zeppelin/achyuttest.csv/trigram.csv', use_unicode=False)
            old_data_df = old_data.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["exploded"])


            result_df = old_data_df.union(result_df)

        else:
            pass


#Save DataFrame in HDFS
        result_df.coalesce(1).write.mode('append').csv('hdfs:///user/zeppelin/achyuttest.csv')

    # Rename file

    #list files in the directory

        list_status = fs.listStatus(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir))

    #filter name of the file starts with part-

        file_name = [file.getPath().getName() for file in list_status if file.getPath().getName().startswith('part-')][0]

    #rename the file

        new_filename = "trigram.csv"

        fs.delete(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir+''+new_filename))
        fs.rename(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir+''+file_name),spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_dst_dir+''+new_filename))

        counter = counter+1
```

I am performing this code on 50K files, and my spark is taking too much time to perform this program. (Passed 2 days and still going ...)

I'm running HDP in Virtual machine(running one node HDP Sandbox)Here is my system specification...

====> Guest OS::

1. Memory: 12930 MB
2. CPU: 6CPUs

===> YARN Specifications::

1.Memory: 4608 MB

2. Maximum Container memory: 4608 MB
3. Maximum Container size(Vcores): 4
4. Number of virtual core: 4

===> Zeppelin Pyspark Interpreter Specification::
1. spark.executor.memory: Blank (it's mean 1g as per specified in the documentation)

So I have two questions.

1. Is my code proper or not?
2. Which value I have to specify in YARN and Zeppelin Interpreter so it will work fast and efficiently.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you reading one file at a time in this - for i in range(1,50001): ? currently all of your data is processing only 1 executor, can you try to use multiple executors i.e load all files at once so that u will get more threads to do this same work ??

Comment: also if possible split your code to process work multiple threads & for single thread.

Comment: @Srinivas I'm new to Spark so can you please refactor my code or provide me some good resource, so I can use multi-threading.

Comment: can you split the code into multiple functions based on functionality ? now you have kept all code into one place ..

Comment: @Srinivas Here what I have to achieve is to perform NLTK on 50K files and save the entire output in a CSV file (there will be three CSV files unigram.csv,bigram.csv and trigram.csv )

For this every time I'm reading the old file and append content at the end, deleting old file and save this content as new file at same location.

I can't determine how to split entire code into functions, can you help me with that?

Comment: @Srinivas can you  please provide efficient code for this program, it will be very helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my first question.

According to the old code, I was making an RDD for each file located in folder, So It was taking too much time (To process 3K files it was taking 19 hr.)

But Now What I have done is to Read all input files in Single RDD operation, and perform all operations on it. (Now New code is taking ~15 min to process 3K files.)

---

### Final Code

**Comments are used for extra understanding**

> Patentdetect-local.py

```
"""
To Run this code
Set Pyspark_python 

$ export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
$ pip install nltk


RUN ON Spark::

$ ./bin/spark-submit file_path/Patentdetect-local.py
"""



import pyspark
import nltk
import string
import os
import re

from pyspark import SparkContext
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

from pyspark.ml.feature import NGram
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,StructType,StructField,StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,array,split,collect_list
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Spark Example').getOrCreate()


Source_path="<path>/*/abstract.txt"

Destination_path="<path>/spark-outputs/parquet/Electronics-50/"



data=sc.textFile(Source_path)


data.persist()
lower_casetext = data.map(lambda x:x.lower())



# splitting_rdd = lower_casetext.map(lambda x:x.split(" "))
# print(splitting_rdd.collect())


# Function to perform Sentence tokeniaztion
def sent_TokenizeFunct(x):
    return nltk.sent_tokenize(x)

sentencetokenization_rdd = lower_casetext.map(sent_TokenizeFunct)

# Function to perform Word tokenization

def word_TokenizeFunct(x):
    splitted = [word for line in x for word in line.split()]
    return splitted

wordtokenization_rdd = sentencetokenization_rdd.map(word_TokenizeFunct)


# Remove Stop Words

def removeStopWordsFunct(x):
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    stop_words=set(stopwords.words('english'))
    filteredSentence = [w for w in x if not w in stop_words]
    return filteredSentence

stopwordRDD = wordtokenization_rdd.map(removeStopWordsFunct)


# Remove Punctuation marks

def removePunctuationsFunct(x):
    list_punct=list(string.punctuation)
    filtered = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in list_punct) for s in x] 
    filtered_space = [s for s in filtered if s] #remove empty space 
    return filtered_space

rmvPunctRDD = stopwordRDD.map(removePunctuationsFunct)

# Perform Lemmatization

def lemma(x):

    lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

    final_rdd = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(s) for s in x]
    return final_rdd

lem_wordsRDD = rmvPunctRDD.map(lemma)

# Join tokens

# def joinTokensFunct(x):
#     joinedTokens_list = []
#     x = " ".join(x)
#     return x

# joinedTokensRDD = lem_wordsRDD.map(joinTokensFunct)


##Create DataFrame from RDD

df = lem_wordsRDD.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["features"])

tokenized_df = df.withColumn("values", explode("features")).select("values")


## Write DataFrame Output

# tokenized_df.write.mode('append').csv(Destination_path)

## Change File-name

# for old_file_name in os.listdir(Destination_path):
#   src = Destination_path+old_file_name
#   dst = Destination_path+"unigram.csv"
    
#   if old_file_name.startswith("part-"):
#       os.rename(src, dst)
        # break


## For Bigrams following commented line is enough
# # tokenized_df.select(F.concat_ws(" ",F.col("values"),F.lead("values").over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(None))))).show()



## Create Final DataFrme 

final_df = tokenized_df.select(collect_list("values").alias("listed_data"))

# final_df.show(truncate=False)

final_df.persist()


## Unigram

unigram = NGram(n=1, inputCol="listed_data", outputCol="unigrams")

unigramDataFrame = unigram.transform(final_df)

unigram_FinalDataFrame = unigramDataFrame.withColumn("unigram_final",explode("unigrams")).select("unigram_final")


## Write DataFrame Outputs

unigram_FinalDataFrame.write.mode('append').parquet(Destination_path)

# Change filename
for old_file_name in os.listdir(Destination_path):
    src = Destination_path+old_file_name
    dst = Destination_path+"unigram.parquet"
    
    if old_file_name.startswith("part-"):
        os.rename(src, dst)


## Bigram

bigram = NGram(n=2, inputCol="listed_data", outputCol="bigrams")

bigramDataFrame = bigram.transform(final_df)

bigram_FinalDataFrame = bigramDataFrame.withColumn("bigram_final",explode("bigrams")).select("bigram_final")


## Write DataFrame Outputs

bigram_FinalDataFrame.write.mode('append').parquet(Destination_path)

## Change filename
for old_file_name in os.listdir(Destination_path):
    src = Destination_path+old_file_name
    dst = Destination_path+"bigram.parquet"
    
    if old_file_name.startswith("part-"):
        os.rename(src, dst)
        # break

## Trigram 

trigram = NGram(n=3, inputCol="listed_data", outputCol="trigram")

trigramDataFrame = trigram.transform(final_df)

trigram_FinalDataFrame = trigramDataFrame.withColumn("trigram_final",explode("trigram")).select("trigram_final")

## Write DataFrame Outputs
trigram_FinalDataFrame.write.mode('append').parquet(Destination_path)

# Change Filename
for old_file_name in os.listdir(Destination_path):
    src = Destination_path+old_file_name
    dst = Destination_path+"trigram.parquet"
    
    if old_file_name.startswith("part-"):
        os.rename(src, dst)
        # break

final_df.unpersist()
data.unpersist()
```